# the problem with unlimited horizontal columns in text, browser does not detect right width for parent of columned element

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, multiple-columns

I have the task of making a horizontally scrolling web page.
One part is column texts, and we don't know how many columns it will be depends on the text.

The page will not have vertical scrolling, so we set a fixed height for wrapper of columns

From what I understand, browsers don't calculate the width of text in columns correctly if the width is larger than the width of the window.

I've tried making the width of the .wrapper auto - it's the same as the width of the window;
I've tried purposely making the .outer-wrapper very wide and setting the max-content for the width of the .wrapper - that doesn't work either.

Here's a snippet - https://codepen.io/the_buddha/pen/poKqLpd

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="fixed">
            <div class="outer-wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <p>Private Sale Drop
                          is scheduled from the 28th of April until May 1st. Preferential Sale Drop is scheduled from the 2nd of May
                          until May 15th. Final Private Sale Drop is scheduled from the 16th of May until the 18th of May. Remaining
                          artworks will be available for sale until June 30th at an increased price.
                          The Venetian-born artist Giovanni Battista Piranesi (1720-1778) is best known for his dramatic prints of the
                          architecture and antiquities of his adopted city of Rome, and for the extraordinary flights of spatial fancy
                          in his celebrated series La Carceri (Prisons).
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: lavender;
    overflow: auto;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    background: lightblue;
    /*   width: 15000px; */
}

.wrapper {
    width: max-content;
    height: 200px;
    border: 4px solid red;
}

.columns {
    column-fill: auto;
    column-width: 350px;
    column-gap: 90px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I expect the borders of the .wrapper element to match the column content.